# Use of recurring words - 'somebody who'

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, logic, errors

> Think of somebody who takes you for granted, somebody who is treating you with disgust, somebody who thinks about you as a thing to use.

Is that sentence well written? I mean the recurring part 'somebody who'- this isn't typical in English, is it? How can we write something meaning the same in other words? And is the quotation is understandable somehow...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! The sentence is well written apart from two points (1) It should be "Think of somebody who ***takes*** you for granted" (2) Sentences must finish with a punctuation mark.  It is perfectly understandable and you don't need to change anything. May I suggest you post questions in [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) ?  I say this because the rest of your English isn't as good as that sentence!

Comment: You can "delete" as much or as little as you want of the "predictably repeated" text ***Think of somebody who*** here (always starting from the left, so it's fine to delete just ***think of***).

Comment: In fact, in this case, you can delete all the _somebody_'s, too.

Comment: Yes, you could reduce it  further to, *"Think of somebody who takes you for granted,  is treating you with disgust, who thinks about you as a thing to use."*   However I prefer your original version. It is more emphatic.

Comment: Your sentence is perfectly correct. The repetition of a word or phrase at the beginning of a series of clauses is called an anaphora.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: idiomatically, I wouldn't be so keen on "resurrecting" ***who*** for the final clause there, after it's been deleted from the second "repeated structure" clause. But I think that's more a matter of style than "correct/incorrect" syntax.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for every answer <3 and for fast replies :))

Comment: You're welcome! Please note that people have voted to close this question. This does not reflect on you. It is just because they consider this more appropriate for [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's sort of poetic -- a stylistic choice.

Comment: You seem to have found us bored but helpful on a Sunday. The closure votes should not worry you. If you had asked what is *anaphora*, you would have been closed because you had not done any research to find out, such as dictionary work. But to go in the other direction from an unidentified concept only illustrated by an example, to the word itself is in general far more difficult. It was a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: Somebody who takes you for granted, treats you with disgust, and uses you

Comment: I'd feel happier with << Think of somebody who takes you for granted, somebody who is treating you with disgust – / ... somebody who thinks about you as a thing to use. >>

Answer (score 1):

The repetition of "*somebody who*" is an example of the rhetorical device known as *anaphora*.

> An anaphora is a rhetorical device in which a word or expression is repeated at the beginning of a number of sentences, clauses, or phrases. A well-known example of this may be found in the speech given by Winston Churchill to the House of Commons on June 4th, 1940: "We shall fight in France, we shall fight on the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and growing strength in the air…"
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anaphora)

It is the repetition of a word or phrase at the beginning of every clause. The repetition emphasises and gives force to the concept of *somebody who ...*

Comment: Note that WS included more heavy-duty punctuation later in the sentence.